# JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name')

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to make a post request to a server but I get the below error.

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.blog.demo.model.Product` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.blog.demo.model.Product` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('name')
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.blog.demo.model.CompanyRequest["products"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]

when I make a request as shown in the json snippet bellow

```
{

"name":"Name",
"products":["name"]
}
```

However when I leave the products list empty, the request is successful.

> Here is my product model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
data class Product(
  var name: String = "",
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
  @JsonProperty var company: Company,
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  var id: Long = 0
){
override fun toString(): String{
    return "{name: ${name}, company: ${company.name}}"
  }
}
```

> Company model

```
  @Entity @Table(name = "company")
  data class Company(
  var name: String = "",

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  var products: List<Product> = listOf(),
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  var id: Long = 0
){
   override fun toString(): String{
    return "{name: ${this.name}, products: ${products.map { it->it.name }}}";
  }
}
```

and here is my controller.

```
   @PostMapping("/companies")
   fun saveCompany(@RequestBody companyRequest: CompanyRequest):ResponseEntity<Company>{
     val company = Company()
     company.name = companyRequest.name
     company.products = companyRequest.products
     return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(companyService.saveCompany(company))
    }
```

I tried adding `@JsonProperty` to my fields but that does not seem to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json incorrect. You pass array of strings in products instead of array of objects.

Try this payload

```
{
"name":"Name",
"products":[{"name": "Name"}]
}
```